# Error While running Spring Application using WildFly server - Mysql Persistance Error - Mysql Datasource not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss

I know this question can be found on web searches and Stack Overflow, but my problem isn't solved and I didn't find the solution.

I am working on a web service but I keep getting some errors when I deploy my .war file. How can I fix this?

```
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql_jdbc_Driver",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.MySqlDS"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"GFI.war#primary\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.MySqlDS]",
        "jboss.data-source.\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.gfiDS\" is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql_jdbc_Driver]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"GFI.war#primary\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.MySqlDS]"
    ]
}
11:51:39,740 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "GFI.war" (runtime-name : "GFI.war")
11:51:39,750 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql_jdbc_Driver (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source."jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.gfiDS"] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.MySqlDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."GFI.war#primary", service jboss.persistenceunit."GFI.war#primary".__FIRST_PHASE__] 

11:51:39,985 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
11:51:39,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
11:51:39,995 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:51:39,995 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 11.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) started (with errors) in 18759ms - Started 762 of 1128 services (136 services failed or missing dependencies, 354 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: It looks like you dont have the MySQL driver installed as a module or included with your application.  I can get an example of how to add it as a module if you like as I needed to do it with MS SQL server